# React-Hooks, thoughts regarding my implementation - good / bad?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have been implementing an architecture pattern that I found [here](https://www.fullstacklabs.co/blog/production-level-patterns-for-react-hooks). The examples below are my implementation of what I learned from that site. I'll admit, with first impressions I am *really* liking the feel of this approach. **But** I am no means an expert on hooks or more advanced "Reacty" knowledge. All of the hooks below are integrated with Redux (the `model`), they decouple state and logic from the `view` (screen), and serve as what I figure to be `controllers`. Again, I'm not an expert on this stuff but that is how it currently feels. So, by all accounts assuming my interpretation is correct what I've been implementing is a hooks-based MVC architecture.

My question is, what are areas of concern with the approach below. I *have* been struggling to write tests for it, but I think that's more in regards to my lack of testing experience than anything else.

So, here is the most involved implementation so far: My signup/registration form that **interacts with redux, component state (formData), and authentication.**

---

**useAuthHooks** (controller?)

> Takes the jwt token and isAuthenticated boolean from the Redux store auth object.
> All forms related to login/registration require access to currently *at most* those elements of formData state. If a user logs in, registers, or logs out, the associate action is dispatched with the correct arguments as needed by Redux.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { logout, login, register } from '../redux/actions/auth';

const useAuthHooks = () => {
  const { token, isAuthenticated } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    username: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    password2: '',
  });

  const { username, email, password } = formData;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const loginUser = () => dispatch(login(email, password));
  const registerUser = () => dispatch(register({ username, email, password }));
  const logoutUser = () => dispatch(logout());

  return {
    state: { formData, setFormData },
    loginUser,
    registerUser,
    logoutUser,
    token,
    isAuthenticated,
  };
};

export default useAuthHooks;
```

**Form** (I don't know what this would be interpreted as in other architectures)

> My Form has a format (either "login" or "register") that is passed in as a prop. My `Form` needs (or at least has access to) everything that exists in the above `useAuthHooks`. Additionally, my form also sends out alerts that are handled in Redux. So, I spread the `useAlertHooks` in as well. Lastly, the format is being used to determine the `FormScreen` output so it get's passed along as a prop.

```
import React from 'react';
import useAuthHooks from '../../hooks/useAuthHooks';
import useAlertHooks from '../../hooks/useAlertHooks';
import FormScreen from './FormScreen';

const Form = ({ format }) => {
  const { ...authProps } = useAuthHooks();
  const { ...alertProps } = useAlertHooks();

  return <FormScreen {...authProps} {...alertProps} format={format} />;
};

export default Form;
```

**FormScreen** (Ok, this one is definitely the view)

> We destructure the props and use them accordingly. Nothing too wild. Don't be put off by all the camel case elements like `<Label>`, `<Input>` for example. They're part of styled-components.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import styles, { P, H200 } from '../../ui/styles/variables';
import RectButton from '../_buttons/RectButton';

const { borders, colors, templates } = styles;

const FormScreen = ({
  format,
  renderAlert,
  registerUser,
  loginUser,
  isAuthenticated,
  state,
}) => {
  const { username, email, password, password2 } = state.formData;

  const onChange = (e) => {
    state.setFormData({ ...state.formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  // # Redirect if logged in
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return <Redirect to="/profile" />;
  }

  const onRegister = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password !== password2) {
      renderAlert('Passwords do not match', 'success');
    } else {
      registerUser();
    }
  };

  const onLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    loginUser();
  };

  const registerForm = (
    <>
      <H200> Create an Account</H200>
      <FormContent onSubmit={(e) => onRegister(e)}>
        <Label htmlFor="username">Username</Label>
        <Input
          type="text"
          name="username"
          value={username}
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
        />
        <Label htmlFor="email">Email</Label>
        <Input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
        />
        <Label htmlFor="password">Password</Label>
        <Input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
        />
        <Label htmlFor="password2">Confirm Password</Label>
        <Input
          type="password"
          name="password2"
          value={password2}
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
        />
        <RectButton text="Register" />
        <Options>
          <P>Already have an account?</P>
          <Link to="/login">Sign in</Link>
        </Options>
      </FormContent>
    </>
  );

  const loginForm = (
    <>
      <H200>Log into Account</H200>
      <FormContent onSubmit={(e) => onLogin(e)}>
        <Label htmlFor="email">Email</Label>
        <Input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
        />
        <Label htmlFor="password">Password</Label>
        <Input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
        />
        <RectButton text="Login" />
        <Options>
          <P>Don't have an account?</P>
          <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
        </Options>
      </FormContent>
    </>
  );

  return format === 'register' ? registerForm : loginForm;
};

export default FormScreen;

// ... Everything below this line was styled-components stuff
```

**LoginPage** (I also have a separate (very similar) page for the register version.)

> For my `LoginPage`, I want the login version of the Form so wallah, I pass in the "login" argument.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Page, CColumn, CHeader } from '../../../ui/styles/layouts';
import Form from '../../../components/_auth/Form';
import Alert from '../../../containers/_alerts/Alert/Alert';

const LoginPage = () => {
  return (
    <Page>
      <CHeader>
        <Alert />
      </CHeader>
      <CColumn>
        <Form format="login" />
      </CColumn>
    </Page>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

The benefits of this approach is I can (and have) very easily add and remove hooks that are not needed in a given `Screen`. They gain access to everything (spread) and ... now that I come to think of it ... maybe can be given specific bits of logic (simply by not spreading) from the custom hooks. Not sure if that will work, but worth a try. Additionally, my hook behaviors are all held in one location, my view's only handle inputs and generic navigational features, and I am respecting the single-source of truth being Redux. That's my takeaway at least. Curious what others think.

Thank you :)